# Angular 8 proxy and oauth2 400 bad request

Tags: angular, proxy, spring-security-oauth2

After upgrading my angular-app from angular 7.2.11 to angular 8.1.3.

Angular HttpClientModule doesn't send my oauth2-secured requests when using the proxy.

- The angular-app works when i deploy it and don't use the proxy.
- The HttpClientModule works when use the proxy but don't use the oauth2-tokens

Proxy-config:

```
{
  "/oauth/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8090",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8090",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Oauth2-config (using @auth0/angular-jwt 3.0.0)

```
HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter
      }
    }),
```

- The oauth2-calls get proxied
- The api-calls get proxied
- The api-calls with oauth2 bearer header result in 400 Bad request.

Comment: it looks like the requests get blocked somehow by the request-header "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors", but this is exactly why i'm using the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution, it seemed my oauth2-token was getting too big and it hit a http-header-limit on the angular proxy.

I have solved it with following command:

`"scripts": {
"start": "node --max-http-header-size=100000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --proxyConfig=proxy.conf.json -o",

},`